# What's the maximum capacity of memory (in bytes) that can be accessed in 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

Also what's the minimum space that a program can occupy in memory?

I know that every register in 8086 have a maximum capacity of 16 bits

Comment: Please avoid asking such general questions here. You can easily get such answers on google. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

The 8086 processor can address 1MB of memory using a [segmented memory model](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200728-00/?p=104012). A memory segment can contain code or data (or both), and a given segment can be up to 64K.

In practice, some of the [memory space](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exyfeng/research/cos/resources/machine/mem.htm) is occupied by an interrupt vector table, BIOS, and by devices such as the memory buffer for graphics cards. The exact amount of addressable *RAM* depends on the hardware configuration.

While 1MB is the limit of memory directly addressable by the 8086 (or in real mode of later processors), additional memory can be mapped into windows of that address space using the bank switching technique.

With MS-DOS, the first standard implementation of bank switching was called LIM (for Lotus, Intel, Microsoft). It allowed switching the physical memory mapped to each of the 4 highest 16KB blocks of memory in the address space, which was referred to as the Upper Memory Area (UMA).

A later specification eXtended Memory Specification (XMS) allowed extended physical memory to be mapped anywhere into the available address space.

Game consoles of the time used similar techniques.

Comment: The limit is 1 MB address space. Bank switching could be used to work with additional memory.

Comment: @rcgldr Thanks for the reminder. That sure brings back some memories.

Comment: The bank switching like mapping is called [Expanded memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory) . [Extended memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_memory) requires an 80286 or later processor.

Comment: Also remember that just because a CPU can address X kb of RAM, doesn't mean that you have that much RAM. For example, let's say you have a Z80 CPU with only 32k of total RAM (including the program code area, stack, etc). Half the address space (most likely the upper half ranging from `&8000-&FFFF`) are going to be unused. Typically, these addresses are mirrors of existing ones, meaning that (in this case) writing a byte to `&9000` is actually writing it to `&1000`.

Answer (score 2):

8086 had a 20-bit linear / physical address space, so 1MiB of RAM + ROM + device memory.

The only mode available on 8086 was what later CPUs call "real mode", where seg:off logical addresses of two 16-bit halves map to linear addresses as `(seg<<4) + off`.  That calculation can go slightly past 1MiB, and on later CPUs / systems, wrapping to 20 bits could be disabled (A20 gate), although that was mostly useful for other modes that set a segment base differently, allowing access to much more memory.

Michael Petch comments that some add-in cards provided a 64K window onto a large amount of physical memory, like up to 32MiB.  So that's like "bank switching".  To access different parts of that space, programs would have to do an I/O operation like perhaps an `out` instruction.  Logically it's a bit like paging to a hard drive or SSD, except that stores go directly to the extra memory, so you can switch away from a modified bank without a write-back first.  And of course performance is very different, latency to switch banks is vastly lower than writing+reading 64K on a rotational hard-drive.  But it's not transparent to software so it doesn't work like having lots of RAM for running a program that doesn't already know about this add-in memory expansion card.

---

**Minimum *program* size depends on the OS.** Under DOS, a 1 byte `.com` file containing `C3` (`ret`) will execute cleanly, returning to an exit system-call the DOS puts into its memory image.  I don't know how much space different versions of DOS require to be available to actually load it; presumably at least a 512 byte disk sector plus space for the PSP (program segment prefix).

On bare metal, a 2-byte ROM with an infinite loop (`jmp $`, i.e. `jmp rel8=-2`) could potentially execute, although you'd only know it by watching the address lines as it re-fetched the code, since of course it couldn't do anything.  (You might possibly need a `cli`, although probably the CPU boots with interrupts disabled.)

If it's all that's hooked up an 8088, it would only have to decode the low bit of the address line to supply each byte separately on the 8-bit bus.  If hooked up to an 8086, it wouldn't have to decode anything any address lines, just a clock and read signal, as the 16-bit but would be fetching both bytes in parallel.  Or maybe you could just hard-wire those 16 pins of the 8086 to power and ground.

Comment: While 1MiB is addressable at any given time, an 8086/8088 machine could have more RAM through proprietary memory cards, or LIM Expanded Memory compatible boards. With LIM usually a 64KiB frame becomes addressable in the memory space above A000:0000 and the amount of memory available on a LIM EMS ISA card was up to 32MiB.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I saw rcgldr's comment on the other answer but hadn't realized that was a real thing that people actually did, not just theoretical. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. By the time the 80286 came out those LIM EMS boards could still work on 80286 machines with the same drivers. There was a very slow driver solution if you wanted to use the Extended Memory of the 80286 and treat part of it as expanded memory (appears like LIM EMS) and was done through EMM286.SYS device driver. On the 80386 the old LIM EMS board were no longer needed as EMM386 could emulate Expanded Memory (LIM EMS) very fast through software by running DOS in v8086 (protected mode) and use hardware paging. This is what EMM386.SYS device driver was able to do.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Updated my answer with a mention of these, and some hopefully reasonable guesswork about what this means in general terms for usable memory.  Feel free to edit if you want, or write your own answer about these add-in boards and I'll edit mine to mention and link it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory there were cards that existed, later things like QEMM/QEMU came out that were software versions, but the emm stuff started with hardware.   so in theory you could have unlimited address space.  but otherwise I think this question is a poster child for so trivial to find that it is not for so folks to find for you.  should be closed.  (seeking external resources (for so folks to read for you/to you))

Comment: based on how the question is asked, the 20 bit segment+offset is most likely the answer to their homework question.

Comment: @old_timer : Based on the title of the question one could argue the ambiguity of what was asked.

Comment: @old_timer: I wasn't much concerned about why the OP wanted to know (since they didn't bother to explain at all), just that there were some interesting things to say that could qualify as an answer to what they actually asked, which future readers might find interesting (as might the OP).  I considered also downvoting the question for this lack of clarity, but ended up not doing so.